# Displaying created record Id in controller of Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

Hi I am writing certain values to database which returns the id of saved record. 
My factory has following

```
return {
    postNewR: $resource('/api/newRec', {}, {create: {method: 'POST'}})
}
```

In my controller I have

```
newR_factory.postNewR.create(recordData, function(data){
   alert(data.id);
});
```

Everything works fine. I can see in browser developer tools that in response it is returning id of newly created value i.e 22.
However in alert box I get undefined.'
Please let me know how i can display the value of id in alert box. 
Thanks

Comment: `created` or `create`? Which is correct?

Comment: so if you replace that alert with a console.log, it logs 22 to the console?

Comment: Can you try doing a `console.log(data)` above the alert to check the data structure of the returned object?

Comment: No it doesnt return 22 ...when I do console.log(data) It gives  "Resource{$promise: Promise, $resolved: true}"

Comment: What exactly does the request and response look like in your browser's *Network* console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `$promise` returned like this:

```
newR_factory.postNewR.create(recordData).$promise.then(function(data) {
    alert(data.id);
});
```

Alternatively, and this is more "angular", you would do it like:

```
var new_record = new newR_factory.postNewR(recordData);
new_record.$save(function(data) {
    alert(data.id);
});
```

Comment: You can also pass a success handler into the method (just like OP is doing)